# cant insert data into mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

Can't insert more than two data's in the mysql database i'm running the code in python using raspberry pi.
the code i used is

```
query="INSERT INTO import(customer,package) VALUES('%s','%s')"
cursor.execute(query,(name,data))
```

it gives an error to check the syntax.

Comment: Please provide the error message.

Answer (score 5):

You also need to add `connection.commit()` after your insert/update queries.

Example

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(*data)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(<query>)
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

When using parameters, you should *not* quote your parameters. That is, your query should be;

```
query="INSERT INTO import(customer,package) VALUES(%s, %s)"
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/newread.py", line 40, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query,(name,data))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),'006078648')' at line 1")

Comment: @MANIVANNAN Is the code in the query the exact code you're getting this error with? Looks like the query you're getting the error on isn't parameterized a'la what you're showing.